# Push в массив элементы по условию

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте есть массив масивов
[ [2,45], [66,89], [77,3]
У нас [2,45] это [age, p]
Если age>55 и p>7 тогда пушать в новый массив значения 'Senior ' если нет - тогда 'Open'

У меня проблема в тому что на эту проверку пушает 2 раза

```js
const dataArray=[[2,3], [90,4], [56,52]]

for (let i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
 let index1=dataArray[i][0]
  let index2=dataArray[i][1]
  // console.log('index1 ', index1, 'index2 ',index2)
  const arr=[]
  const seniorOrOpen=dataArray[i].map(()=> (index1>55 && index2>7) ? arr.push('senior') : arr.push('open') )
  console.log('seniorOrOpen ', arr)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно вы не очень правильно составили алгоритм

```js
const dataArray = [[2,3], [90,4], [56,52]];

const seniorOrOpen = dataArray.map(i => i[0] > 55 && i[1] > 7 ? 'senior' : 'open');

// Можно использовать
console.log('seniorOrOpen ', seniorOrOpen)
```

В чем были проблемы:

- Два цикла - вы повторили всю операцию столько раз, сколько элементов в массиве.
- `map` выполняет операцию над каждым элементом массива.
  Например `[1, 2, 3].map(i => i*2)` вернёт `[2, 4, 6]`. Если надо просто пройтись по массиву, то используйте `forEach`

Comment: где я тупил? ....